# need help on sat vocab app beginning process for android

Tags: java, android

So I am new to Android Programming but I absolutely love it. Luckily, I already know java   (: There are still some things that confuse me such as fragments or what not. I want to write an SAT app. can anyone give me some directional guidance on where to start? I would really really appreciate it. Im not sure if each card should become it's own fragment? Anything would help such as how to store the words/definitions. Or if you could give me some topics to research that would aid my app making, i would appreciate it !! Tips on flashcard making in general are welcome too. THANK YOU~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally think it depends on what type of phone/ screen size you are targeting. If you would like to target also larger screen ones like tablet then fragments will be the right way to go. With fragments you can add and remove certain view from the large screen.

Some guide for fragment that i found quite useful myself: 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

This is also one of my fav site for android tutorials:
http://www.androidhive.info

Anyway, welcome to android world! :)
Hope that helps

Comment: haha thank you! I am looking at the website and it's so helpful!

Comment: sure! :) kindly vote up the answer if you think its good so that it can benefit other users too :)